# RecursiveDirectoryIterator() not showing empty directories

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP's RecursiveDirectoryIterator to list a set of directories. The issue I am having is that it seems to be skipping any empty directory it hits. Any ideas how to make it list empty directories?

Here is a clip of the code I am using:

```
 $iterator =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root));
 $result = array();

 $prefix_length = strlen($root) + 1;
 foreach($iterator as $file)
 {      
   if($file->isDir())
   {

      $result[] = dirname(substr($file->__toString(), $prefix_length));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
$iterator =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! :) Can you explain why `~RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` will not work? Not work means it will only list folders in the first level.