# PHP: Creating a tar archive containing symlinks and empty directories

Tags: php, tar, phar

I'd like to have a simple PHP script (no external dependencies) that is able to create a verbatim archive of a directory. This directory can contain anything that's valid, including empty directories and broken symlinks.

Input directory looks like this:

```
.:
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 101633 1014 1502 Apr 23 17:21 a.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 101633 1014    6 Apr 23 16:10 empty-directory
-rw-r--r--  1 101633 1014    0 Apr 23 15:52 emtpy-file
-rw-r--r--  1 101633 1014    7 Apr 23 15:52 file-w-contents
drwxr-xr-x  2 101633 1014   18 Apr 23 16:39 nonempty-dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 101633 1014    6 Apr 23 15:52 symlink-target-dir
lrwxrwxrwx  1 101633 1014   18 Apr 23 16:12 symlink-to-dir -> symlink-target-dir
lrwxrwxrwx  1 101633 1014   10 Apr 23 16:14 symlink-to-emtpy-file -> emtpy-file
lrwxrwxrwx  1 101633 1014   11 Apr 23 16:25 symlink-to-nonexistent -> nonexistent

./empty-directory:
total 0

./nonempty-dir:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 101633 1014   0 Apr 23 16:39 file

./symlink-target-dir:
total 0
```

The 'official' solution to this is using Phar, but it omits symlinks and empty directories, and throws an exception on broken symlinks (looks like it wants to follow them by default - I found no way to disable this behavior).

```
$phar = new PharData('output.tar');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$phar->buildFromDirectory("/z");
```

Result:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: phar error: unable to open file "symlink-to-nonexistent" to add to phar archive in /z/a.php:9
```

After removing the dangling symlink, the following tar file is created:

```
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1502 2020-04-23 17:37 a.php
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               0 2020-04-23 17:37 emtpy-file
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               7 2020-04-23 17:37 file-w-contents
-rw-r--r-- 0/0               0 2020-04-23 17:37 nonempty-dir/file
-rwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2020-04-23 17:37 symlink-target-dir
```

(Note that the empty 'symlink-target-dir' got included, albeit not as a directory, but a regular file.)

Is anyone aware of a small standalone library that is able to create a proper tar archive including all the directories and links?

Comment: Have you tried the [Follow Symlinks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants.follow-symlinks) option or [using a custom iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromiterator.php)? Check this on how to [include empty directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149401).

Comment: @msg I can't add empty directories manually, as phar->addEmptyDir() requires phar.readonly to be set to 0, which I cannot do (this script should work in any environment regardless of PHP settings).  Re:links, I don't see any methods in Phar to add symlinks, so I don't know how a custom iterator will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have found nothing that would satisfy my needs, I decided to create my own version.

It's available at https://github.com/koszik/php-tar